Is it possible to auto-convert HTML/CSS/JS code into a Stack Snippet?
Why can't there be a automatic feature that detects if its HTML/CSS/JS code and auto makes it into a Stack Snippet? This would be very helpful and nice because I always find so many posts WITHOUT a Stack Snippet.

"Why cant there be a automatic feature that detects if its html/css/js code and auto makes it into a stack snippet?" - because not everything can be run in a stack snippet?

html css js code can. thats what i said in my questin :/

Not all HTML, CSS, and/or JS code can. Off the top of my head, there's a bunch of node.js code that stack snippets don't support, some questions are about frameworks stack snippets does not support, and there are a large amount of libraries that aren't auto-loaded, and have to be manually and separately added for a stack snippet to work

Not all HTML can actually run in a stack snippet. For example you can write HTML with jinja2 templates, Django templates, various different tools etc. it mostly looks like HTML but it won't render properly in snippets

Not to forget about SCSS/SASS and other various CSS extensions that can be misidentified as plain CSS, but not run if attempted interpreted as CSS, or if typescript is involved with HTML and/or CSS. Completely other languages being involved with plain HTML is also not a great use-case for stack snippets

You can have the following JS myObject.myMethod() - I assure you it's valid JS. It's also not runnable as a snippet. Well, unless you want to get an error but then it's not a very useful snippet.

This is a "just" type of question without actually using the word. "Why can't there be a automatic feature that just detects if its HTML/CSS/JS code". Just-questions are the product of not thinking it through. Because NOTHING is simple enough that you can "just" do it. Certainly not programming related things.

I'd actually prefer the opposite - detect when a Stack Snippet has been used for unrunnable code and turn it into a standard code block


Why can't there be a automatic feature that detects if its HTML/CSS/JS code and auto makes it into a Stack Snippet?

A Stack Snippet is defined as runnable code sandboxes of the front-end languages HTML, CSS, and JS for use within a Stack Exchange post
Notice the runnable. I highly doubt that it is trivial to move HTML, CSS and/or JavaScript found in a post into a runnable Stack Snippet. I'll even argue that creating a Stack Snippet is as difficult as creating an Minimal Reproducible Example. Given lot of questions come without an MRE, converting those to a runnable snippet is complex for a real human and (god forbid) steps too far for an AI.
This skims over scenarios that can't be easily supported by Stack Snippets, like server interaction, browser features that are blocked for security reasons to name a few.

This would be very helpful and nice because I always find so many posts WITHOUT a Stack Snippet.

Yes, that is a common problem, specially for new questions. I suggest to leave a comment and ask the OP to create a Stack Snippet when you expect the code, markup and style is self contained and will run by itself. I would not edit these posts as you might by accident fix or break something that would render the post useless.
